# C macro with expression unwanted result

Tags: c, macros

I am running the following program and getting a result as 9 7, I understood why 9 is the output but I can't figure out why I'm getting 7 as output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define sqr(i) (i*i)

int main()
{
    printf("%d %d", sqr(3), sqr(3+1));
    return 0;
}
```

For the second function that is `sqrt(3+1)` how the micro is getting expanded and how Im getting 7 output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have the compiler or IDE preprocess the file and show you how the macro expanded.

In your case `sqr(3+1)` expands to `(3+1*3+1)`. Now the precedence of C operators means that the multiplication is done before the addition. So `(3+1*3+1)` -> `(3+3+1)` -> `(7)`.

You can fix this by defining your macro this way, with parentheses around the argument:

```
#define sqr(i) ((i)*(i))
```

Comment: I have forgotten to check its expansion in IDE. Thanks btw.